# After GRUB I get error: invalid video mode specification 'text' booting in blind mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15 but I get some errors below. I tried to remove some of them including `procps`. After that I get `error: invalid video mode specification 'text' booting in blind mode`. How to fix it?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
17 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up cups-browsed (1.0.67-0ubuntu2.6) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups-browsed, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package cups-browsed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up procps (1:3.3.9-1ubuntu8) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service procps
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-daemon:
 cups-daemon depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up rsyslog (7.4.4-1ubuntu14) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript rsyslog, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up avahi-daemon (0.6.31-4ubuntu4) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript avahi-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package avahi-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avahi-utils:
 avahi-utils depends on avahi-daemon; however:
  Package avahi-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package avahi-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.
 cups depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez-cups:
 bluez-cups depends on cups; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez-cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-server:
 openssh-server depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-gutenprint:
 printer-driver-gutenprint depends on cups (>= 1.3.0); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                           dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-gutenprint (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-splix:
 printer-driver-splix depends on cups (>= 1.5.0-3~); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-splix (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of telepathy-salut:
 telepathy-salut depends on avahi-daemon; however:
  Package avahi-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package telepathy-salut (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up brltty (5.2~20141018-4ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service brltty
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package brltty (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-printers:
 indicator-printers depends on cups (>= 1.5); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-printers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of inxi:
 inxi depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package inxi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                           Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-148-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups-browsed
 procps
 cups-daemon
 rsyslog
 apport-gtk
 avahi-daemon
 avahi-utils
 cups-core-drivers
 cups
 bluez-cups
 openssh-server
 printer-driver-gutenprint
 printer-driver-splix
 telepathy-salut
 brltty
 indicator-printers
 inxi
W: No priority (or zero) specified for pin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: Using recovery console I get kernel panic. Currently, I have access to the filesystem using a live cd of ubuntu that has mounted the original boot drive to create backup. How to repair the original boot disk?
[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 15 has long been unsupported, could you try something newer?

Comment: I don't know if I can, maybe...... but right now I can not even boot and I don't have ssh :-(